# Setting up env variables in github actions workflow yml

Tags: python, github-actions

So I'm trying to set up an env variable, and print it to see if it actually is set up.

Bellow is only an example on how I m trying to set the env vars, in realiy I'm trying to set secrets as env variables but it dosent work.

I use the env variables in python scripts, but they are not being set os.getenv("key") returns none whatever I'd do

```
name: test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]
    
permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      SERVICE_NAME: daily monitoring

    steps:
    - name: "Setup env vars"
      run: echo "Test"
      env:
        TEST_VAR: "test variable value"
        
    - name: "Var is "
      run: echo "var is ${{ steps.outputs.TEST_VAR }}"
```

For the above yml

Setup env vars step logs:

```
Run echo "Test"


echo "Test"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    SERVICE_NAME: daily monitoring
    TEST_VAR: test variable value
    Test
```

Var is step logs:

```
Run echo "var is "
var is
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting two environment variables (one globally, and one specific to the "Setup env vars" task. In both cases, they're working correctly: if you were to modify your "Setup env vars" task like this...

```
    steps:
    - name: "Setup env vars"
      run: |
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME"
        echo "$TEST_VAR"
      env:
        TEST_VAR: "test variable value"
```

...you would see the values you expect.

But in your "Var is task"...

```
    - name: "Var is "
      run: echo "var is ${{ steps.outputs.TEST_VAR }}"
```

...you're not asking for an environment variable. You're asking for `${{ steps.outputs.TEST_VAR }}`, and there are a few problems there:

1. The format for that expression is `steps.<step_id>.outputs.<name>`, and you're not setting the `id` for any of your steps.
2. You're not setting outputs in any of your tasks

If you want to define outputs for a task, you need to follow [these docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter). That would look something like:

```
jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      SERVICE_NAME: daily monitoring

    steps:
    - name: "Setup env vars"
      id: envvars
      run: |
        echo "TEST_VAR=$TEST_VAR" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        echo "SERVICE_NAME=$SERVICE_NAME" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      env:
        TEST_VAR: "test variable value"
        
    - name: "Var is "
      run: |
        echo "${{ steps.envvars.outputs.TEST_VAR }}"
        echo "${{ steps.envvars.outputs.SERVICE_NAME }}"
```